# How to remove reciprocal records from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the follwing form:

```
   head      relation    tail
0   two  DistinctFrom     one
2   two           IsA  number
12  one       Antonym     two
15  one           IsA  number
```

from the above dataframe I would like to keep only one record for,  where the head entity is same as tail entity and tail entity is same as head entity. For example from the recodrs with index zero and index 12, I would like to keep only one, may be first or last, anything will do.

For example, after keeping first record the final dataframe will look like:

```
   head      relation    tail
0   two  DistinctFrom     one
2   two           IsA  number
15  one           IsA  number
```

Or

when keeping last record, the datframe would be like,

head      relation    tail 
2   two           IsA  number
12  one       Antonym     two
15  one           IsA  number

Thanks.

Comment: you con think of some better names for the columns, head and tail are like pandas methods ... confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to index the dataframe with both the `head` and `tail` columns, `sort` them and check which are `duplicated`:

```
df.loc[~df[['head','tail']].T.apply(sorted).T.duplicated()]

   head      relation    tail
0   two  DistinctFrom     one
2   two           IsA  number
15  one           IsA  number
```

Answer (score 2):

Create subset for both column, sorting by `np.sort` for improve performance, create DataFrame and filter by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['head','tail']], axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()]
print (df)
   head      relation    tail
0   two  DistinctFrom     one
2   two           IsA  number
15  one           IsA  number
```